# How to correctly allign two imageViews in Android for all display sizes using constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have 2 image views in Android. One is a wind turbine pole and the other one wind turbine blades. How can I set the layout constraints such that the wind turbine blades are always correctly attached to the pole? They should fit for different screen resolutions.

Here is the screenshot of the layout editor:

[image]

Here is the xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_windTurbinePole"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wind_turbine_pole" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_windTurbineBlade"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_windTurbinePole"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_windTurbinePole"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_windTurbinePole"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wind_turbine_blade" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update**: The desired image should look like a "real" wind turbine where the blades are on the pole. The bigger picture is that I want to make an animation in Android in which the blades rotate.

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe the intended meaning of "correctly attached to the pole" and the desired outcome? Maybe also provide examples that may appear incorrect for certain screen resolutions

Comment: @VladGuriev: Thanks Vlad for your comment. I added a picture of the desired outcome

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think you can try adding `android:translationY="...dp"` to place one of the images closer to the other

Comment: @VladGuriev: Thanks Vlad for your comment. But how can I assure that they correctly alligned to each other especially considering different screen sizes and resolutions

Comment: Looks like they're going to resize proportionally; your translationY value is a result of some percentage of the blades' image height, for example, 40dp is always 1/3 of 120dp. However, you can try checking it on different emulators.

Comment: @VladGuriev: Thanks Vlad for your comments. I really appreciate it. But how can I make sure that the image has the same proportions independant from the screen size? This is really difficult in Android. Using dp does not make the images device independant (in contrast to its name) as the image will be way smaller on a bigger screen with regard to the proportions of the display. On a tablet the image should be bigger but with dp you can't be indepandant of the device. Maybe it makes more sense to use percentage values for sizing the image like `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.224"`

Comment: Ah, you need the proportion of the total wind turbine height to the screen height to be exactly the same, right? e.g. exactly 1/2 of the total screen height?

Comment: @VladGuriev: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I think this is the only way to really make layouts device independent

Comment: @VladGuriev: any further comments on how to proceed? As stated before, I would like to define a percentage of the screen for the translationY attribute instead of dp because with dp the layout does not get device independant. I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: I don't remember an option to define the translationY attribute as a percentage, but you can set it in code in [doOnPreDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).doOnPreDraw(kotlin.Function1)) where the real sizes are already known

Comment: not a percentage, but the real calculated `translationY` based on the blades' real height

Comment: @VladGuriev: Thanks for your comment. I don't understand what you mean. Further, I don't use Kotlin but Java, this is why I can't work with you posted link. But in generall I don't know how to continue. I want the two images to fit independant from the screen size. You can't do this with dp as `translationY`

Comment: wrote a sum-up of the above as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the view height to be a fraction of the screen height, you can use something like this:

```xml
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.224"
```

Then, if you need to move the pole closer to the blades, you can do it in code in [doOnPreDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).doOnPreDraw(kotlin.Function1)).

You can use it from Java, too:

```
androidx.core.view.ViewKt.doOnPreDraw(windTurbinePoleView, view -> {
    windTurbinePoleView.setTranslationY(- FRACTION * windTurbineBlade.getHeight());
    return null;
});
```

Here I'm moving *windTurbinePoleView*, you can apply a similar approach to *windTurbineBladeView*. `FRACTION` is a constant that represents the distance between the blades' image bottom and the central circle bottom divided by the blades' image height.

If the 'doOnPreDraw' part isn't resolved, you can add the dependency `androidx.core:core-ktx:VERSION`. Alternatively, you can use `windTurbinePoleView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(...)` with the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad for your answer. I have some questions. 1) Why do I have to use  `androidx.core.view.ViewKt` before the method doOnPreDraw? This looks strange. 3) Why do I have to return `null` in the method? Am I defining a new method or am I just calling it? If I call it, there is no need for null (at least I have never seen anything like this) 3) How did you calculate `Fraction` and why did you calculate it. Can you show me the code. Actually in my case the pole position should be fixed and the blades should be translatedY

Comment: 1) It's the full path, but you can move this part to the `import` section, simply place the cursor on `ViewKt` or `doOnPreDraw` and press Option+Enter.
2) You call it. It's a Kotlin-Java interop trade-off when using lambdas that return `kotlin.Unit` from Java
3) `FRACTION` is not calculated on code, it's a constant. You simply measure the distance between the blades' image bottom and the central circle bottom in an image editor, then similarly the blades' image height, then divide the first value by the second.

Comment: @VanessaF if you move the blades, you don't need the "-" here:
`windTurbineBlade.setTranslationY(FRACTION * windTurbineBlade.getHeight())`

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad for your answer. It helped a lot. I really appreciate it.